# What is the best database to store ~50,000,000 values?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I need to store ~50,000,000 values which contains only id (auto-increment) and varchar(32). And then show the random value for each pageload. Of course I wouldn't use RAND().

So, is MySQL good for it if I work with PHP? Or should I learn some other database which is more optimal?

Comment: I did geographic searches with tables that size, both on MySQL (simple stuff, such as stuff in range of A from x,y) and PostgreSQL (with definitely more complex stuff, using PostGIS), with no performance issues at all. Just avoid "SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1", maybe.. :P

Comment: BTW, just for testing, I just run a "select * from bigtable order by rand() limit 1", where bigtable is a table as you described, with 1000000 random records: it took 0m0.791s on my laptop - so, not bad at all, I tought it would be worse..

Comment: @redShadow: in case of doubt, I'd use RAND to generate a number and then `WHERE key = ThatNumber`

Comment: @gbn, yeah, I understood that from your question.. Howerver, I'd rather use a randomizing function on the php-side instead, since *RAND() is not meant to be a perfect random generator. It is a fast way to generate random numbers on demand that is portable between platforms for the same MySQL version.* (see: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_rand)

Comment: I compressed the phrase "I understood that from your answer, and I think the 'Of course I wouldn't use RAND()' in the question was referred to that" into "I understood that from your question" - yeah, maybe it's time to go to sleep :)

Comment: Ok, now the strange thing: I am populating a table with the 50000000 records just to do some performance testing; meanwhile I was trying with `select * from bigtable where id=floor(rand() * (select max(id) from bigtable))`, that returns a variable number of records.. (approx. zero to three); the same problem using `count(*)` instead of `max(id)`.. anyone can explain why is this happening?

Comment: ..just figured it out: it evaluates the `floor(rand() .. )` expression for each row. You should use a variable to temporarily store the random id: "set @randomid=(select floor(rand() * (select max(id) from bigtable))); select * from bigtable where id=@randomid"

Comment: Here are the execution times of some queries I run on the 50M records MyISAM table on MySQL.. http://pastebin.com/RZJfkwTj

Comment: @redShadow In the `ORDER BY RAND()` approach, assuming that the `ORDER BY` run in `O(N LG N)`, for 50x more records it would take `50 * (25.6 / 19.9) * 0.8s` or ~51 seconds. Granted, the server is likely faster, but the 50x records also require more data-access which could swamp the IO, kick more pages out of cache, etc. In any case ... not a fun query on basic hardware except in one-off situations ;-) (Yes, there are machines that will easily scoff at this query.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

50 million rows is a rounding error for the mainstream RDBMSes.

Use MySQL if you know it, or pick one you're comfortable with.

To pick one row out of 50 million, you generate a number between 1 and 50 million and pick that single row. So why not use RAND as a number generator? (Edit: but not in the ORDER BY as per redShadow's comment on question)

Comment: I've seen it suggested before (link not included ;-), that, instead of picking a single row by index (e.g. with LIMIT), it more efficient (again from memory, likely DB specific) for a table with a densely-packed sequential PK structure to just pick a random PK in that range (say, try 10 a query) and then pick the first row that existed (or try again). The need to pick several/try again is to handle cases of "gaps", but there ought not to be many (relatively speaking) in 50 million records...

Comment: @pst: I can see why: LIMIT/TOP implies ORDER BY and you're at the mercy of the optimiser. A straight = onto a unique key is probably more consistent. Even if they have the same plan in practice

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a *lot* of queries MySQL is probably fine.

If you don't delete records and the auto-increment range is continuous a key-value store is perfect for this. However you will need something (SQL, if you are lazy :)) that gives you an atomic counter so you can insert new key-value pairs.

Answer (score 0):

Think of splitting your data into several tables: if you ever have to change the schema of your table you have to rebuild a table with 50 million rows instead of say 10 tables with 5 million rows.